# I can't understand which file upload with Appliciation Loader

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

i'm just about to submit my application in iTunes connect, and i can't figure out how to upload my application with Application Loader. It tell me to chose file, but i can't chose .zip file, and my application folder.

Please help me figure out how to wrap my project in correct extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on how to upload your app for review: [Tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-upload-an-app-to-the-app-store-with-xcode-4/)

Most of this is done in xCode. You are not uploading a zip file. You compile the app in xCode and upload the results of that.

Hope this helps!